# Let N represent the set of natural numbers $\{1,2,3, \ldots, 14, 15\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $\mathbb N$ represent the set of natural numbers $\{1,2,3, \ldots, 14, 15\}$. Let $X = \{ n \in \mathbb N \mid n\ge 5 \}$, let $Y = \{ n \in \mathbb N \mid n \le 10 \}$ and let $Z = \{ n \in \mathbb N \mid E(n) \}$, where $E(n)$ is a predicate that means "$x$ is even".

Would this basically mean the following:

$$X = \{5, 6, \ldots, 15 \}$$ 
$$Y = \{ 1, 2, \ldots, 10 \}$$
$$Z = \{ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14 \}$$

It's a silly question I know, but Id like to be sure of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the answers are correct provided if I understand your notation  correctly, that is you are trying to express "less than or equal to" and "greater than or equal to" for $X$ and $Y$.

$X = \{ n \in N | n \ge 5\} = \{ 5, 6 , \ldots, 15\}$.

$Y = \{ n \in N | n \le 10\} = \{ 1, 2 , \ldots, 10\}$.